# Which JavaScript engine is used by XSLT

Tags: javascript, xslt

What JavaScript engine is used by XSLT processors (when using a JS extension element)? Does each use an embedded JS engine, or do some look for a OS-level component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [XSLT specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) does not say anything about JavaScript. However, some XSLT engines do support extensions using JavaScript or other languages. Which JavaScript engine is used depends entirely on which XSLT engine is used.